# jQuery Tabs : How can I add function to show a next/previous button on jQUery tabs?

Tags: jquery-ui, firefox, tabs

Is there a way to mimic the function of Mozilla Firefox tab function to [jQuery Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) that, when there are multiple of tabs, it adds a next button to view next tab after the last displayed tab.

[image: jQuery multiple tabs]

I want to add this next button(encircled),  to the jQuery tabs UI functionality. Also, if possible, to add the animation on the menu tab to move tabs as next/previous button is clicked, like on the said browser.

[image: Firefox functionality next button]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[This could help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927534/next-prev-functionality-for-the-jquery-tabs) You will need custom logic.
[This CSS trick](http://css-tricks.com/jquery-ui-tabs-with-nextprevious/) can also help out. You can tweak the logic for the placement of the next button and you are good to go.

Comment: Thank you for this idea, this will add on logic! But then, I forgot to add on my question, if there's  any way to click that next/prev button and let us say 10 tabs will animate to move along the menu tab. Thanks again!